# How to Reset Remote Debugger Connections in VS2012 Once Set

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

In Visual Studio 2012, you can select `Remote Machine` from the Build Toolbar

[image: SelectRemote]

On the first click, the `Remote Debugger Connections` dialog popups up and allows you to set where you're debugging against.

[image: RemoteDebugger]

The problem is once the value has already been set, navigating to Remote Machine or right clicking anywhere on it will not allow you to change the original configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value from that popup is stored in your project file.  You can access it by going to the Debug tab on your project properties.  You can change the value there, or if you clear it out, you can get the popup again next time you navigate to remote debugger

[image: Change Remote Machine]